# When clearInterval will be called - When the timer changes or When the render is unmounted with which the setInterval is associated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval, react-component-unmount

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem.
**When the setInterval associated with a particular renders gets cleared?**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  },[]);

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get cleared on component unmount event :

```
useEffect(() => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id); // <-- get called on component unmount
  },[]); // <--- get called once component mounted/rendered first time
```

For more details : **[DO READ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-without-cleanup)**

> **When exactly does React clean up an effect?**
>
> React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we
>   learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This
>   is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before
>   running the effects next time.

Comment: thanks @vivek  I have an another question that suppose take the above example and instead of doing setState(count+1) we'll do (count+0) then on next Render or the 2nd render will be same as of First Render(as no change of state). Then what will happen to the First render interval calls - Will they be called forever or not ? - As First render is same as of 2nd render so it won't be unmounted thus cleans up effect won't happen of 1st Render.

Answer (score 0):

I think your *actual problem* is that the timer only updates once, right? Well thats because you [*lied to React about your dependencies*](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies), your effect uses `count`, add that as an dependency:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   let id = setInterval(() => {
     setCount(count + 1); // here you use count
   }, 1000);
   return () => clearInterval(id);
 }, [count]); // here you have to tell react about your dependencies
```

Now the function returned from the effect will be called whenever `count` changes, or when the component unmounts. So you could actually write your code as:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   let id = setTimeout(() => {
     setCount(count + 1);
   }, 1000);
   return () => clearTimeout(id);
 }, [count]);
```

This basically does: *Whenever 'count' changes, shedule a timer to change 'count' again in 1 second*.

However, using an interval that runs as long as the component is mounted would work too, but for that to work we need to (1) remove all dependencies (`count`) and (2) get the latest `count` somehow. Fortunately the state setter also takes a callback:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   let id = setInterval(() => setCount(count => count + 1), 1000);
   return () => clearInterval(id);
 }, []); // we don't lie anymore
```